# Only manual start of downstream multiphase job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a MultiJob Project on Jenkins. I have job Main that runs jobs A, B, C. In MulitiJob Phase section, "Continuation condition to next phase when jobs' statuses are: Successful" is set. All of the jobs use common workspace. Is there a way to configure job C in such a way that it would be triggered only manually? So that if i start job Main, only jobs A and B would be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. the way to do so is to add Boolean parameter and set his default to false and check it every time you run the build manually.

1. First create a boolean variable call the variable runC.
   [image]
2. Configure the C job in the MultiJob with conditional [image]

This job will run only if the checkbox selected and that will be  selected if it will run manually.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution!